# Google Recaptcha tooltip translation

Tags: c#, localization, tooltip, recaptcha

I'm trying to translate the tooltip required message on ReCaptcha(English to Spanish), I was able to translate recaptcha itself and trying to translate tooltip message also.

Below is the code I used to translate.

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=es'></script>
```

```
 window.onload = function () {
        var $recaptcha = document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response');
        if ($recaptcha) {
            $recaptcha.setAttribute("required", "required");
        };
    }
```

```
<div class="row mt-md-1">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group form-inline P0">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey='@key' required></div>
                <label id="lblreCaptcha" name="lblreCaptcha"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: That message is from Chrome, not Recaptcha. It's a standard browser feature. Set your browsers language and it should change.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG, Updating browser settings worked. Is there a way that I can set or update using JS?